# How many ways could the guests arrange themselves on a four person couch

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are 33 guest at your home for a dinner party in how many ways could the guests arrange themselves on a four person couch

I really not understand this question form where to start can someone explain please

thanks ..

Comment: I think some permutations are missing in the answers so far.  Couldn't one or more seats be empty?

Comment: @RustyLemur If there are 33 people, the couch is guaranteed to fill up.

Comment: I would submit the question to the OP, since 30 or more guests may prefer to stand or sit in other locations.  It seems reasonable to assume that no more than 4 people at a time should be considered, but I think it is also reasonable that fewer than 4 people should be considered as valid arrangements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the 33 guests, choose 4 to sit on the four-person couch: ${33 \choose 4}$. After that, arrange those 4 guests on the couch in all possible ways: $4!$. Hence the final answer is:
$$
{33 \choose 4} 4!
$$

Comment: It seems like this answer is a little high level. If the OP does not understand a simple permutations question, it seems unlikely that he understands the binomial coefficient

Comment: Isn't this the same as `33 P 4`?

Comment: Yes, @MathFun123 's answer is clearer/better.  You probably wouldn't use the choose notation if you're looking for permutations instead of combinations.

Comment: @Josh I disagree. You can use combinations for permutations and it is also clear to do it that way! But maybe his answer was easier to get when first studying combinatorics!

Comment: @BrunoReis Using the notations for combinations when you want permutations is the opposite of 'clear', it's conspicuously misleading.  But yeah, I guess it's easier for him if he doesn't know.

Comment: @Josh I don't see it that way... Maybe it's because for me combinations can be completely related to permutations and it's a clear reasoning... But I understand what you're saying, since in combinatorics the Binomial Coefficient is studied after simple permutations!

Comment: @Josh I don't see it that way... Maybe it's because for me combinations can be completely related to permutations and it's a clear reasoning... But I understand what you're saying, since in combinatorics the Binomial Coefficient is studied after simple permutations!

Comment: @BrunoReis Being able to reason about it doesn't make using X instead of Y when it's really Y more clear than just simply using Y.

Answer (score 15):

If I understand the question correctly; we have one couch for four people and 33 guests so 29 guests have to stand.

On the first place on the couch 33 people can sit, on the second place only 32 can sit (because one is already sitting on the first place), and so on...

So $33\times 32\times 31\times 30=982080$ ways.

Comment: Do we also need to count "no-one sitting in that space" as a possibility?

Answer (score 4):

This is a case of permutations without repetition. To visualize this better, imagine you have a total of $n$ balls and you want to place them in $r$ boxes. Each box can contain only $1$ ball. Clearly, the number of boxes filled cannot surpass $n$, since $n \geq r$.

You want to see the number of different ways you could do that. In other words, you want to find the number of permutations. For the $1^{st}$ box, you could place any one of the balls. Hence, there are $n$ options. For the $2^{nd}$ box, you have $1$ fewer ball, so there will be $(n-1)$ options. For the $3^{rd}$ box, there will be $(n-2)$ options. Keep repeating until you reach the $r^{th}$ box, where there will be $(n-(r-1))$ options.
Let’s say $P$ represents the total number of permutations for $n$ choose $r$.
$$P_{(n, r)} = n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-3)...\cdot(n-(r-1)) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$
In your question, there are $33$ guests and a $4$-person couch, so $n = 33$ and $r = 4$.
$$P_{(33, 4)} = \frac{33!}{(33-4)!} = \frac{33!}{29!}$$
All factors from $29$ to $1$ will cancel.
$$P_{(33, 4)} = 33\cdot 32\cdot 31\cdot 30$$
$$\boxed{P_{(33, 4)} = 982080}$$

Comment: How would visualising _n_ balls and _r_ boxes be better than visualising 33 people and a single couch?

Comment: Just gave a general example briefly explaining the concept. Could’ve been anything really.

Comment: Given it could have been anything wouldn't it make more sense to use people and seats? I don't think it makes it clearer to use a totally different example (especially ones using n and r) and then saying that the seating example is the same by analogy...

Answer (score 4):

To fill all four seats, there are $33\times 32\times 31\times 30=\frac{33!}{29!}$ ways as others have said.

To fill three seats, there are $\binom 43=4$ ways to choose which seats are to be filled, and then $33\times 32\times 31$ ways to fill them, so $4\times33\times 32\times 31$ arrangements. Similarly there are $\binom42\times33\times 32$ ways to fill two seats, and so on. So the total number of options with up to four people sitting are
$$\sum_{k=0}^4\binom4k\frac{33!}{(33-k)!};$$
if you consider the empty couch not to be a valid option then your sum would start from $k=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lets break down the problem.

No of guests=33,
No of people can sit =4

Let's select 4 person from 33 guests
That's

```
33c4
```

or

```
33!/{(33-4)! x 4!}
```

now we have selected 4 guests form 33 guests. They can arrange themselves in 
4! ways.

So final answer is:

```
{33c4}x{4!}
```

Comment: Please use MathJax when answering. Also I do not believe that this answer adds anything to the previous answer by Bruno Reis (and in my opinion suffers from the same problems)